# Get the response after a send in sequence in WSO2ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

How do you get a sequence to return a response from a proxy? I have tried Call, Callout, Send & Respond. My client makes the service request & just get a 200 response. My endpoint service gets called but its response seems to be discarded. If I use a pass through proxy (i.e. no sequence) all is okay but then, I have no log mediator or statistics.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="sequence_myservice" trace="enable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log separator="">
    </log>
    <send>
       <endpoint key="conf:/myservice"/>
    </send>
</sequence>
```

Comment: solved - should have (re)read the documentation, needs In/out. sorry if i wasted anyone's time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`<in>` and `<out>` mediators](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/In+and+Out+Mediators) inside your sequence, check the [documentation of in and out mediators](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/In+and+Out+Mediators).

- Build you request in the inSequence and call the `<send>` mediator
- You will get the response inside the outSequence

Here is a code example:

```
<sequence name="main" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <in>
        <log level="full"/>
        <send>
            <endpoint>
                <address uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService"/>
            </endpoint>
        </send>
    </in>
    <out>
        <!-- here is your response -->
        <send/>
    </out>
</sequence>
```